# Regex double operators are single counting

Tags: java, regex, double, operator-keyword

I want to check if there is a double operator. For example :

int result = x+y;

results in `operatorCounter = 2`, it is working. But:

```
for(;i<size;i++)
```

results in `operatorCounter = 3` while it should be `operatorCounter = 2`.

My regex `String doubleOperatorPattern = "\'.\\++\'";`

Operators I want : (++) (--) (==) (&&) (||)

```
public void findOperator(String file){
    String operatorPattern = "['+''-''*''/''=''<''>''<=''>=''&''|''^''!''\\-?']";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(operatorPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        operatorCounter++;
    }
    String doubleOperatorPatternString = "['==''++''--''&&''||']";
    Pattern doubleOperatorPattern = 
    Pattern.compile(doubleOperatorPatternString);
    Matcher doubleOperatorMatcher = doubleOperatorPattern.matcher(file);
    while(doubleOperatorMatcher.find()){
        operatorCounter--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, can you add more explanation of what is the problem. How operator count is 2 for x+y ?

Comment: Hi to you too, (=) one operator (+) one operator 2 operator. I'm finding all the operators. No problem here. Problem dual operators. Is counting 2 times. For example : (==) is equal to. But regex counts it twice. I want to count once.

Comment: do you want to match (+) and (++) as well right?

Comment: String doubleOperatorPatternString = "['==''++''--''&&''||']";
        Pattern doubleOperatorPattern = Pattern.compile(doubleOperatorPatternString);
        Matcher doubleOperatorMatcher = doubleOperatorPattern.matcher(file);
        while(doubleOperatorMatcher.find()){
            operatorCounter--;
        }

Comment: can you edit the question and format the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the `++` and other two characters operators like `+=` or `-=` first before single character operators the `+`, `-` and `=`. If we follow [Operators docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and add all the Java operators the regex gets nasty due to escaping:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "\\+\\+|--|" +          // ++ --
        "\\+=|-=|\\*=|" +       // += -= *=
        "/=|%=|&=|\\^=|" +      // /= %= &= ^=
        "\\|=|<<=|>>>=|>>=|" +  // |= <<= >>>= >>=
        "<<|>>>|>>|" +          // << >>> >>
        "==|!=|<=|>=|" +        // == != <= >=
        "&&|\\|\\||" +          // && ||
        "\\+|-|~|!|" +          // + - ~ !
        "\\*|/|%|" +            // * / %
        "\\+|&|\\^|\\||" +      // + & ^ |
        "<|>|=|" +              // < > =
        "instanceof"            // instanceof
);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("for(;i<size;i++)");
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
  count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

but it will find `<` and `++` and print 2.

Do note that this regex still doesn't support ternary operator `? :`.

Comment: Such was better : 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "\\+\\+|--|\\+\\+|&&|\\+\\+|==|\\||\\\\instanceof"); 
Thank you so much. The document helped me. It's working now.

Comment: @MuhammetÖmer added other operators from docs, it's a monster regex so added comments. If it helped please accept the answer.